Updated lspconfig but still cannot find config `nextflow_ls`
I am using Neovim v0.10.1 on a Linux machine (CentOS 7.9).
I am trying to set the Nextflow Language Server, but can't connect it to my Neovim buffer.
I have installed nvim-lspconfig into the recommended place, which is:
~/.config/nvim/pack/nvim/start/nvim-lspconfig

When I run :scriptnames from Neovim, I see that this plugin is loaded.
My problem occurs when I try to run :lua =require'lspconfig'.nextflow_ls.setup{}. It tells me
[lspconfig] config "nextflow_ls" not found. Ensure it is listed in `configs.md` or added as a custom server.

But nextflow_ls exists in the configs.md of my new lspconfig install. Why is it not seeing it?

Okay I figured it out and this is a bit dumb:
I had modified a line in the nextflow_ls.lua file to customize the cmd parameter, but apparently the syntax was wrong, causing this configuration to be ignored.
